# How to create prepared statements for mariadb, node.js and websockets

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, mariadb, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a db query using a prepared statement.

I have:

```
connection.query('
INSERT INTO myTable (column_1, column_2, column_3) 
VALUES (?`, [col_1_val]`, ?`, [col_2_val]`, ?`, [col_3_val]`)`)
```

Obviously this is pretty wrong. In the above example, all variables are numbers. But in production some will be strings.

I've also tried lots of other things, such as:

```
connection.query('
INSERT INTO myTable (column_1, column_2, column_3) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?`, [col_1_val, col_2_val, col_3_val])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statements in node.js can be written as:

```
connection.query("
INSERT INTO myTable (column_1, column_2, column_3) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [col_1_val, col_2_val, col_3_val])
```

For those variables you wish to convert to strings:

```
connection.query("
INSERT INTO myTable (column_1, column_2, column_3) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [col_1_val.toString(), col_2_val.toString(), 
col_3_val.toString()])
```

The MariaDB getting started page provides an example of prepared statements: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/

Comment: That's not really a prepared statement (which to be fair wasn't available in the node.js connector when you wrote your reply). While the documentation department hasn't gotten the memo, the connector now supports true prepared statements: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/whats-new-in-mariadb-connector-node-js-3-0/